# Statistical Test for showing variance in peak values of two different populations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, anova, p-value, bimodal

I am publishing a paper and one of the reviewers requested that I provide a statistical method to show the difference between peak values (peak value = tallest bin in a histogram) of two populations. I am referring to the figure below, where "TfR" is one population (shown in black) and "hSTf" is the other (shown in pink). As you can see, the black population appears to be bimodal. So ideally, I would just compare the first peak of this black population to the pink population. Please note that the y-axis is normalized probability.

[image]

What statistical tests can I use to compare these two distributions?

The reviewer stated "The p-value/ANOVA test result for example might help the reader for the quantitative understanding." How might I run such a test on these two populations?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I do not see that the black distribution is bimodal - it looks to me as if its mode is in the second bar, just like the light pink distribution

Comment: Does looking at the log of $\Delta I(pA)$ allow for a better comparison of the two distributions?

Comment: "How to compare two distributions" is different from "how to compare the tallest bin in two histograms". It's not clear what you want to test.